# Перетаскивание окна без заголовка в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Сделал окно без заголовка:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    String fxmlFile = "/fxml/MainDialog.fxml";
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    **stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);**
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}
```

Нужно сделать возможность перетаскивание окна при зажатии ЛКМ на любой области окна. Как это задать? Скорее всего есть свойство, но не могу найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Denis пример подходящий, использовал его более компактно без BorderPane.
Может кому пригодится

```
private double xOffset;
private double yOffset;

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    String fxmlFile = "/fxml/MainDialog.fxml";
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            xOffset = stage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
            yOffset = stage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
        }
    });
    scene.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            stage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
            stage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
        }
    });

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто измените ваш метод `setOnMousePressed` на:

```
bp.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        xOffset = primaryStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
        yOffset = primaryStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
    }
});
```

и метод `setOnMouseDragged` на:

```
bp.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
        primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
    }
});
```

<sub>[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173956/how-to-drag-undecorated-window).</sub>